# TypeError: WalletLib.WalletClient is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, jestjs, mocking

I'm using a custome SDK in my React Native project and importing it as:

```
import * as WalletLib from 'wallet-lib';
```

and then using its sub classes and function like below:

```
const client = new WalletLib.WalletClient(
  'http://dev-s-wallet.bgdom.com/',
  'https://dev-a-wallet.bgdom.com/',
);
```

This is working fine for application but when I write test using jest it gives me errors.

```
Test suite failed to run

TypeError: BoaWallet.WalletClient is not a constructor

   8 | import * as WalletLib from 'wallet-lib';
   9 |
> 10 | const boa_client = new WalletLib.WalletClient(
     |                    ^
  11 |   'http://dev-s-wallet.bgdom.com/',
  12 |   'http://dev-a-wallet.bgdom.com/',
  13 | );

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/utils/bWalletLibCall.js:10:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/screens/authenticated/overviewTabs/PendingTab.js:27:1)
```

I'm mocking it as below:

```
jest.mock('wallet-lib', () => {
  return {
    WalletLib: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      WalletClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {};
      }),
    })),
  };
});
```

But it still giving me same error. How can I resolve this.

Thank you!